# EAR app on weblogic produces no output in a clustered environement (log4j)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have an EAR (composed from a WAR and and EJB JAR) that i deploy on weblogic, and log4j is configured in this EAR.

When i deploy my EAR in a single server, the log is correctly produced and i can see it at the root of my domain.

When i deploy the EAR to a cluster environment (with two servers), i see in the database that changes are made, and i can interact with the webservice contained into the WAR, but no log file is created nor updated.

Here's my `log4j.xml` configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="MYLOGFILE"
        class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <param name="File" value="MYLOG.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="2MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="80" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} (%3X{IdThread}) [%X{IdDem}] %-5p %-15c{1}: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="MYLOGFILE" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I also tried to change the file name to this: `<param name="File" value="MYLOG_${weblogic.Name}.log" />` so i can have a different log file per server instance, but it doesn't change anything. And i tried this too: `<param name="File" value="C:\MYLOG_${weblogic.Name}.log" />`, but still, no log file.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the two servers that were in the cluster i was deploying to, were having a machine assigned to them (while they were installed locally).

So i just went to the weblogic administration console -> Environement -> Servers, then i selected each server (after i shut it down) and i just changed [Configuration -> General -> Machine](http://localhost:7001/consolehelp/console-help.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=page&helpId=Corecoreserverserverconfiggeneraltitle#core.server.serverconfiggeneral.machine) from `MyMachine` to `none`.

After restarting the servers, the log files appear in the right locations.